# Relationship between $M\otimes_A N$ and $M\otimes_B N$

Tags: ring-theory, tensor-products

In an exercise I'm doing, we are considering a commutative ring $A$, an $A$-algebra $B$, and two $B$-modules $M,N$.

Then they consider $M,N$ as $A$-modules without ever defining the scalar product. My guess is the following: if $*$ denotes the scalar product of $M$ as a $B$-module, and $\cdot$ the scalar product in $B$ as an $A$-module, then we can define the scalar product
$\circ: A \times M \to M$

by $$a\circ m = (a\cdot1_B)*m$$

I've checked and this operation satisfies the properties that scalar multiplication of modules should obey, but I'm not sure if this is the most common/natural way of doing this.

My second question regarding this issue is, if $M,N$ are also $A$-modules, that means that we can form two tensor products: $M\otimes_A N$ and $M\otimes_B N$ is there any way of relating these two, or from going from one to the other?

Comment: $B$ is bigger than $A$, so quotienting by $B$ ought to yield something smaller than quotienting by $A$, so $M\otimes_B N$ ought to be smaller than $M\otimes_A N$. Indeed, there is a surjection $M\otimes_A N\to M\otimes_BN$ given simply by $m\otimes n\mapsto m\otimes n$. If $B$ is commutative then this is an $A$-module homomorphism, else $M\otimes_BN$ is not naturally an $A$-module so we can just say it's additive.

Comment: Are your rings commutative? @Eduardo

Comment: Yes @MartinBrandenburg

Comment: Ok, then $$M \otimes_B N = (M \otimes_A N)/\langle bm \otimes n - m \otimes bn : m \in M, n \in N, b \in B \rangle = \mathrm{coker}(M \otimes_A B \otimes_A N \to M \otimes_A N).$$ The proof is a one-liner with the correct POV. I will not explain this here, since the question is probably a duplicate (did you use the search function on the site?) and I will be punished by the MSE police when I post answers for duplicate questions 

Comment: In this post, I asked two questions. The second one regarding the tensor product is featured in a similar question (9y ago if I'm not mistaken), but I did not understand the answer to that question. Regarding the first question, I couldn't find anything about that @MartinBrandenburg